# Prove that $z$ is not in the cone of $V$ iff there exists a vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Take a collection of $m$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , say $V=\{v_1,v_2,...,v_m\}$. We say the vectors $z\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is in the cone of $V$ if and only if there exists non-negative numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_m$ such that $z=\sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_iv_i.$Prove that $z$ is not in the cone of $V$ iff there exists a vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $z$ is less than $90$ degree from 
>   $w$ but every $v_i\in V$ is at least $90$ degrees from $W$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's Assume that $\ Z \in C(V)$,
$$\
\implies Z = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_iv_i \text{ } \text{ ;}\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ } \lambda_i \geq 0 \text{ }\text{ } \forall i \in [m]
$$
Taking inner product with $\ w$,
$$\
w^TZ = w^T(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_iv_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{m}\lambda_i(w^Tv_i)
$$
Since, $\ Z$ is less than 90 degree from $w$, $w^TZ$ the term on the left is positive.
Similarly, $w^Tv_i \leq 0 \text{ } \forall i$. This shows us that the term on the right is negative.

Required Result Follows.